# Bayes Theorem as a sql query

Tags: mysql

I am working with Bayes' theorem, but am finding it difficult to come up with a certain query. I am using MySQL, and this is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
    EVENTID  NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
    EVENT    CHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EVENTID)
);

CREATE TABLE EVENTDETAIL (
    EVENTID   NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL,
    LOCATION  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    PRICE     VARCHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
    DOE       DATE         NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY  VARCHAR(29)  NOT NULL,
    SCORE     VARCHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (EVENTID) REFERENCES EVENT(EVENTID)
);
```

I have to show all the attributes in `eventdetail` table. for example I have to show the `NAME` and all the `EVENTDETAIL`S of an event which is on 18 March 2013 in Glasgow, but there are two different events with different scores and I have to create a query which shows the result with the best score.

Here are the two lines of result from a query I'm trying

```
EVENT                LOCATION             DOE       PRI SCO
-------------------- -------------------- --------- --- ---
Wicked               Glasgow              18-MAR-13 20  20
Rangers FC           Glasgow              18-MAR-13 34  29
```

I want the second one to be on top, because it has a better score (`29` vs. `20`).

How can I do this?

Comment: Show the two rows you get and the values for the SCORE column and tell us which one you consider "best" and why.  I may be that an ORDER BY clause is all that you need.

Comment: Chapter 10 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel" covers Naive Bayesian Models (which is the application of Baye's theorem).  (http://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Using-SQL-Excel/dp/0470099518/ref=cm_cr_pr_pb_i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the row with the highest score, use an ORDER BY clause with a LIMIT expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   EVENTDETAIL
WHERE  LOCATION = 'Glasgow'
   AND DOE = '2013-03-18'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Your question title is a misleading because you already have your score.  This question does not have anything to do with calculating a Bayes Model score.

Comment: Sorry I am using the bayes theorem in the query thats why I used it in the question! Also I'm new to stackoverflow so learning the website! Thanks soo much for your help! :)